# database search via username

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

I'm developing a call log system, and for tracking purposes the manager wants each user to be logged in upon entry.

I have a module that displays the current logged on user with the code below. I would like for the system to search the table "TBL_Users" for the username and in the text boxes display all the information pertinent to that username. Should that user not be in the database i need to display an error and not allow the user to progress into the system. I'm aware i may need to use a Dlookup but I'm unsure how to code this.

```
    Option Compare Database

Private Declare Function apiGetUserName Lib "advapi32.dll" Alias _
    "GetUserNameA" (ByVal lpBuffer As String, nSize As Long) As Long

Function fOSUserName() As String
' Returns the network login name
Dim lngLen As Long, lngX As Long
Dim strUserName As String
    strUserName = String$(254, 0)
    lngLen = 255
    lngX = apiGetUserName(strUserName, lngLen)
    If (lngX > 0) Then
        fOSUserName = Left$(strUserName, lngLen - 1)
    Else
        fOSUserName = vbNullString
    End If
End Function
```

After playing around with Dlookup for a while, I need the text-boxes to populate on form load. This is the Dlookup i used.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

Windows_Logontxt = fOSUserName()

'agentname = DLookup("Agent_Name", "TBL_Users", "Windows_Logon=" & Windows_Logontxt)

End Sub
```

Comment: "I'm aware i may need to use a Dlookup but I'm unsure how to code this. " - *Everyone* is going to be unsure when trying something for the first time, so that is no excuse. Read [this](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/access-help/dlookup-function-HA001228825.aspx) and then go ahead and try it anyway. Then come back and edit your question to say "Here is how I tried to use `DLookup()`: ..." and tell us what happened.

Comment: Edited question above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems *Windows_Logon* and *Windows_Logontxt* are text values, so enclose *Windows_Logontxt* in quotes when you create the string for the third argument to `DLookup`.

```vb
DLookup("Agent_Name", "TBL_Users", "Windows_Logon='" & Windows_Logontxt & "'")
```